# How do I give myself permission to write on 2nd internal hard drive for NPM installs, permanently on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, npm, npm-install, macos-catalina

I'm currently working on a project that I want to migrate to a 2nd hard drive since I'm trying to share the drive between Windows and my Mac OS so that I can work on it in either OS. I've been trying to do some npm installs in my Mac OS but it keeps giving me

`npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Volumes/Storage/.../node_modules/...`

I did a sudo chown to give myself access to the drive but I don't think it works because newly created folders in node_modules aren't affected after creating them, thus giving me that error. Is there any way I can work on an external drive without getting these checkPermissions errors?

Comment: What filesystem do you use on that drive? You can run this in Terminal to check `diskutil list`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I formatted it as Ex-Fat on my MacOS but it's saying Microsoft Basic Data under diskutil

Comment: under the 'Disk Utility' GUI it says Windows NT File System though...